# Why can I prove ⟦ ( ∃ x. P ) ∧ ( ∃ x. Q ) ⟧ ⟹ ∃ x. (P ∧ Q)?

Tags: isabelle

I'm an Isabelle beginner, learning the basics. To my surprise, I just proved

```
lemma "⟦ ( ∃ x. P ) ∧ ( ∃ x. Q ) ⟧ ⟹  ∃ x. (P ∧ Q)"
apply ( auto )
done
```

in Isabelle/HOL. Now assuming that P and Q range over arbitrary predicates, this is false, just instantiate P to x = 1 and Q to x = 2.

Of course the mistake must be on my side, but where is my misconception?

Comment: I don't know much isabelle syntax. But shouldn't `P` and `Q` be sensible to `x`? In other words `P(x)` and `Q(x)`, otherwise the statements are true, regardless of the value of `x`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As was already indicated in the comment, `P` and `Q` in your example are *not* predicates, they are simply Boolean variables. If you type `term P`, you will get simply `bool`. Since HOL types are nonempty, `∃x. P` is equivalent to `P` and similarly for `Q`, so your assumptions force `P` and `Q` to be `True`, which obviously implies the statement you proved.

What you meant is

```
lemma "⟦(∃x. P x) ∧ (∃x. Q x)⟧ ⟹  ∃x. P x ∧ Q x"
```

This is wrong, and simply by writing down the lemma, quickcheck will already provide you with a counterexample automatically.

Also note that the brackets ⟦…⟧ are not required for a single assumption (like in your case). Furthermore, it is uncommon to use the HOL conjunction operator ∧ to combine assumptions. You would more commonly state this lemma as

```
lemma "⟦∃x. P x; ∃x. Q x⟧ ⟹ ∃x. P x ∧ Q x"
```

or

```
lemma "∃x. P x ⟹ ∃x. Q x ⟹ ∃x. P x ∧ Q x"
```

This form is easier to handle than the one with the HOL ∧, since you can instantiate particular assumptions.